# systemd action when a service fails?

Tags: systemd

Is there a standard way to get systemd to execute a command when a service fails? For example, send an email to somebody (or a passive alert to Nagios).

I realise I can write a wrapper around the `ExecStart` command, but I had hoped for something less ad-hoc.

Answer (score 4):

*OnFailure=
A space-separated list of one or more units that are activated when this unit enters the "failed" state. A service unit using Restart= enters the failed state only after the start limits are reached.*

Source: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

One hacky way to test failures is to run the service with User=Dummy and then, while the service is running, destroy or modify the user Dummy using the command line.